# How to compute mean squared distance of the segmented boundary from the ground truth boundary in python

Tags: python

I have two images say **gt** the ground truth image and **a** the segmented image. I want to calculate the MSD between these two. I wrote a code. Just want to know if the code below is okay.

```
grd=np.array(measure.find_contours(gt, 0.99))
grd_x=np.array(np.transpose(grd[:,:,0]))
grd_y=np.array(np.transpose(grd[:,:,1]))

seg=np.array(measure.find_contours(a,0.99))
seg_x=np.array(np.transpose(seg[:,:,0]))
seg_y=np.array(np.transpose(seg[:,:,1]))

distance=[]
for i in range(0,len(seg_x)):
     temp_vector_x=seg_x[i]*np.ones(len(grd_x))
     temp_vector_y=seg_y[i]*np.ones(len(grd_y))
     tt=np.array(np.sqrt((np.square(temp_vector_x-grd_x))+(np.square(temp_vector_y-grd_y))))
     ttmin=tt.min()
     distance.append(ttmin)

results=(np.sum(distance))/len(seg_x)
```